# Why am I getting 403 permission denied from Apache 2.4.7 on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, apache-http-server

I've read about a dozen different answer to this but none of those answers seem to help. Here is the issue in a nutshell:

```
@bos-lpqum:/var/www$ curl http://localhost/html/index.html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /html/index.html
on this server.</p>
<hr> 
<address>Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

When I try to access from another machine (after opening the right ports) I get a timeout.

I ran `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www` but still getting the same 403. I can provide any conf files you'd like to see.

I copied my sites-enabled config over from another machine running apache 2.2.22. Locally i'm running 2.4.7.

update: Permissions look accurate to me:

```
@bos-lpqum:/var$ ls -lt
total 64
drwxr-xr-x  4 root     root     4096 May  7 23:12 centrifydc
drwxrwxrwt  2 root     root     4096 May  7 22:48 tmp
drwxrwxr-x 21 root     syslog   4096 May  7 08:00 log
drwxr-xr-x  2 root     root     4096 May  6 07:59 backups
drwxrwsrwt  2 root     whoopsie 4096 May  6 07:35 crash
drwxrwsrwt  2 root     whoopsie 4096 May  5 13:09 metrics
drwxr-xr-x 10 root     root     4096 May  5 12:53 spool
drwxr-xr-x 20 root     root     4096 May  5 12:50 cache
drwxr-xr-x 79 root     root     4096 May  5 12:50 lib
drwxr-xr-x  3 www-data www-data 4096 May  5 12:40 www
drwxr-xr-x  3 root     root     4096 May  5 12:12 dell
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root     root        4 May  4 15:41 run -> /run
drwxr-xr-x  4 root     root     4096 Mar 18 11:19 centrify
drwxr-xr-x  2 root     root     4096 Mar 18 08:19 games
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root     root        9 Mar 18 08:03 lock -> /run/lock
drwxrwsr-x  2 root     mail     4096 Mar 18 08:03 mail
drwxr-xr-x  2 root     root     4096 Mar 18 08:03 opt
drwxrwsr-x  2 root           50 4096 Apr 19  2012 local
```

tried the curl with https (instead of http):

```
$ curl https://localhost -k
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error or
misconfiguration and was unable to complete
your request.</p>
<p>Please contact the server administrator at 
 sdhub-ops@domain.com to inform them of the time this error occurred,
 and  the actions you performed just before this error.</p>
<p>More information about this error may be available
in the server error log.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 443</address>
</body></html>
```

`allow from all' is not anywhere to be found:

```
$ egrep -r "allow.*from" /etc/apache2/*
/etc/apache2/mods-available/info.conf:  # Uncomment and change the "192.0.2.0/24" to allow access from other hosts.
/etc/apache2/mods-available/status.conf:    # Uncomment and change the "192.0.2.0/24" to allow access from other hosts.
```

original config:

http://pastebin.com/vaHUqccf

new config:

http://pastebin.com/mTzvDk6X

000-default.config:

http://pastebin.com/jJtKtHTV

Comment: Since this is your server, this probably isn't the solution, but 90% of the time, if I go to a site and get a 403, changing HTTP in the url to HTTPS fixes it.

Comment: That might shed some light on it, but now I get a 500 instead of 403.

Comment: To answer this question, we need your configuration, especially the one that you copied.

Comment: see update @daniel

Answer (score 2):

In Apache 2.2, the directive was `allow from all`, but in Apache 2.4, this has become `require all granted`.  Search for `require all granted` in the documentation.

Comment: I wish that was the case because EVERYTHING on the internet says to change this, but a grep of my /etc/apache2/* does not show any "allow from all"

Comment: did you add require all granted anyway? did you grep case sensitive?

Answer (score 0):

I don’t see any [`<Directory>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directory) blocks in your configuration. While the Apache default is to allow access to anything, it’s very likely your Linux distribution ships a secure default config *disallowing* access unless specifically allowed.

A minimal Apache (2.4) virtual host would look somewhat like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.com

  DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com

  <Directory "/var/www/example.com">
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I added my default config. That should cover it, no?

Comment: I don’t know what you added, but if it’s what’s in the edited question, it’s bad. Never ever allow more than you absolutely need to.

Comment: ...this is for my local dev environment. I just want to get the server working so i can develop locally.

Comment: need to access from exactly one other machine.